# Why vector images on button size looks different

Tags: c#, wpf, vector

I am using C# WPF, this is a weird one, I got a +(Plus) vector image on buttons, there are 6 buttons that are exactly the same underneath each other with exactly the same vector image, the buttons are all the same size but the vector images comes out different when I run the application, please let me know if you like to see my XAML:

Please see my example image here [Button Vector Issue Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqncN.png)

Answer (score 1):

You should add

```
SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
```

To what ever is using the vector image so the images are not anti-aliased.

[SnapsToDevicePixels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.snapstodevicepixels(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I have my button, inside the button is my grid, inside the grid is my image, do I put the SnapsToDevicePixels on the image, becuase I have tried all 3 and it made no difference, usually SnapsToDevicePixels does the job

Comment: also, it is only when my screen is not maximised, I only noticed that now

Comment: You can also try to set UseLayoutRounding="True"